# Mostrar en una tab el contenido de un modelo

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-models

Buenas estoy tratando de mostrar el contenido de un modelo en un template, el problema es el siguiente: No se como hacer para mostrar el contenido dependiendo de la opción a la que le des click. Como estoy usando un `for` en el template solo se me muestra el contenido del ultimo registro de la tabla, si alguien me puede ayudar o sugerirme que puedo hacer.

Mi modelo:

```
class Beneficio(models.Model):
    OP_DEP = (
        ('Afiliacion', 'Afiliacion'),
        ('Bienestar y Seguridad Social', 'Bienestar y Seguridad Social'),
        ('Beneficios del Trabajador', 'Beneficios del Trabajador'),
        ('Créditos', 'Créditos'),
        ('SISA', 'SISA'),
        ('Inversora', 'Inversora'),
    )
    autor = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    dependencia = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        choices=OP_DEP,
        default='AA'
    )
    beneficio = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    texto = HTMLField('Texto')
    fecha_creacion = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.dependencia
```

Mis vistas:

```
def bafiliacion(request):
    afi = Beneficio.objects.filter(fecha_publicacion__lte=timezone.now())

    return render(request, 'noticias/beneafiliacion.html', {'afi': afi})
```

Mi template:

```
    <div class="Beneficios">

    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-4">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
            {% for item in afi  %}    
            <li><a href="#{{item.beneficio}}" data-toggle="tab">                    {{item.beneficio}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}     
            </ul>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="tab-content">
                {% for item in afi %}                                            
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="{{item.beneficio}}">{{item.texto|safe}}</div>
                {% endfor %}    
                </div>
            </div>
```

esta es una imagen de lo que se supone me tiene que mostrar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si le doy click a la opcion que dice sobreviviente me muestra el texto que beria mostrar, pero al darle click a las otras dos opciones no me muestra nada en el respectivo tab

Comment: Hola, si entiendo bien quieres mostrar una pestaña por cada registro de la tabla ?

Comment: correcto eso es lo que quiero hacer, y que cuando marque una pestaña me muestre el texto correspondiente, pero al  terminar el loop for, solo queda la ultima tab activa (sobreviviente) y de alli no cambia

Comment: Revisa el código de tu plantilla. Tu problema no está relacionado con Django, sino con Bootstrap.